# What are the different types of geometry in literature that may be used for deep learning?

Tags: math, geometric-deep-learning

Recently, I asked a [question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/31526/18758) on the concept of a manifold and received an [answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/31533/18758) that points to a relatively new subfield of deep learning named *geometric deep learning*.

In the `preface` of the paper titled [Geometric Deep Learning Grids, Groups, Graphs, Geodesics, and Gauges](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.13478.pdf), there is a mention of three types of geometry that do exist in the literature.

> For instance, **Euclidean geometry** is concerned with lengths and angles, because these properties are preserved by the group of Euclidean transformations (rotations and translations), while **affine geometry** studies parallelism, which is preserved by the group of affine transformations. The relation between these geometries is immediately apparent when considering the respective groups, because the Euclidean group is a subgroup of the affine group, which in turn is a subgroup of the group of **projective** transformations.

The three types of geometry they mentioned are Euclidean, affine and projective. I want to know the complete list of types of geometry that do exist in the literature, if relevant to geometric deep learning.

What are the types of geometry in the literature that may be used for deep learning?

Comment: Hi there, if you are interested in GDL, you can check out those lectures https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2-dEmQeTfQ8YVuHBOvAhUlnIPYxkeu3, they are given by the authors of this paper and closely realted to this paper.

Comment: Yeah, thanks @SwaksharDeb